# Reboot after removing an application from Blackberry - javaloader.exe

Tags: blackberry, reboot, javaloader

I have a quick questions. My Blackberry gets restarted after I uninstall an application (OS 5, 6, 7) using the JavaLoader. Is that the expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: When you uninstall a module that uses persistent storage, the Blackberry gets restarted. It does not matter whether you uninstall it using Desktop Manager, or an uninstall is issued from BES, or the user manually uninstalls it from the device.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running at the time of uninstallation - either in foreground or in background, the device will restart.